# How can I have a shell script log into a remote server and execute imqcmd there?

Tags: shell, networks

I want to write a shell script to connect to the remote server and execute a command (any linux command).

I am using linux and want to prepare a shell script which can login to the virtual directory server and execute a given command.

I.e. if I want to execute the `imqcmd` command, how can I do this?

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You could start with mentioning what operating system you are using on client and server.

Comment: I am using linux and want to prepare a shell script which can login to the virtual directory server and execute a given command i.e if i want to execute imqcmd command . how can i do this?

Comment: You apparently also want the remote command to ask for user input. Are there any other requirements not shown in the question? Could you say exactly what you want it to do?

Comment: belongs on unix/linux site, not programmers

Comment: After executing the command through shell ,the command then asks for user inputs . Than how this can be done ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I asked, but the good people at Unix & Linux didn't think the question was up to their standards. And I can't say I disagree with them, this needs a lot more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the direct ssh command for command execution it asks for password after you enter this command. Any way the below shell script shall work.

`#!/bin/bash
ssh root@ipaddress yourcommand`

Comment: And if after executing the command again it asks for the user input i.e user and password then what shall be added here?

Comment: I mean you need to automate this command with providing password ???

Comment: yes, providing username and password.

Comment: You cannot password embedded with this command. One possible solution is to generate the keys between two machines and provide the keys during ssh command. The below link will be helpful http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Can't there be anyway out without generating keys?